# "Possible outcomes" in dice roll

Tags: combinatorics

So, I am "relearning" about Combinatorics. I just started with "An introduction to combinatorics and graph theory (David Guichard)", and I'm really confused regarding one of the examples

> **EXAMPLE 1.2.4**: Imagine that we have three dice that can change color: one can be red or white, one green or white, one blue or white. If they have colors red, green, and blue, there are P(6; 3) = 6*5*4 possible outcomes. If we arrange the dice in all 120 possible ways and take a picture, we get 120 obviously different photographs. (...)

In this particular example, what "possible outcomes" refers to? I expected all possible outcomes to be 6^3 = 216, as the arrangement seems to matter due to the different colours, and no explicit requirement regarding repetition in values is presented. In my opinion, P(6;3) represents the outcomes of a roll where the three dice have different "numbers".

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You really should include the paragraph preceding the example to give appropriate context to your question.  Also, the example doesn't stop where you do.  The author eventually divides by $3!$ to get $20$ as the answer.   https://www.coursehero.com/file/p2q8f80f/This-is-quite-a-general-sort-of-problem-DEFINITION-123-The-number-of/

Comment: From what you reproduced (which btw matches the link https://www.coursehero.com/file/p2q8f80f/This-is-quite-a-general-sort-of-problem-DEFINITION-123-The-number-of/), your expectation seems spot on to me, and the example seems flawed.

Comment: I think that the author's *intention* is to teach about permutations, where repeated values are not allowed. However, even reading back a few paragraphs to get the context, in my opinion dice are a bad way of presenting examples of permutations, because of the exact conflict of expectations as in your post.

Comment: That is right; after in the same example, the author divides by 3! but in an scenario where all dice are white. I'm interested in only this fragment. Regarding appropriate context, I think this to be a self-contained example. if you have the same book, can you help me clarify if my mistake is there?

Comment: This example refers back to example 1.2.1, in which Guichard considers outcomes when three dice are rolled and no two of the dice show the same face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dice are allowed to have the same number, the correct number of permutations is $6^3=216$, just as you surmised.

On the other hand, were the dice not allowed this property, we'd get $6C3$ or $\frac{6!}{3!3!}$ which is the $20$ eventually stated. The $120$ is $6P3$, the simple difference between the two is that $6P3$ will allow $1,3,6$ and $6,1,3$ to both be counted, as well as any other reshuffles of those three digits, whereas $6C3$ will only include $1,3,6$.